# redirect radio button in JavaScript does not work

Tags: javascript, velo

I would like to redirect this radio button to the lightbox page, but the function does not work.it's related to the Wix platform. I define a radio button when the user clicks on it, open a new lightbox that fills information. for example, I have a Tutor radio button, when users checked it show the new lightbox. Could you please help me? here is my code:

```js
import {registeruser} from "backend/assignment";
import {authentication} from 'wix-members';  
import {doRegistration} from 'backend/assignment';
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
import {doApproval} from 'backend/assignment';
import {myAssignRoleFunction} from 'backend/assignment'
import {currentMember} from 'wix-members';
import { authorization } from 'wix-members-backend';
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';

function event() {
  let User1 = $w('#accountAssign').value; // "new value"
  if (User1 === "Tutor") {
    wixWindow.openLightbox("tutorbox")
      .then((data) => {
        let receivedData = data;
      })
  }
}

$w.onReady(() => {
      const email = "$w('emailInput') ";
      const password = "$w('#passwordInput')";
      const firstName = $w('#nameInput').value;
      const lastName = $w('#surnameInput').value;
      const accountType = $w('#accountAssign').value;
    }

    $w("#accountAssign").onChange((event) => {});

    let labels = [$w('#accountAssign').value];

    doRegistration(email, password, firstName, lastName, accountType, labels)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Confirmation email sent.');
    });
```

Comment: Please [define "does not work"](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). What do you mean "redirect a radio button"?

Comment: I do not see a radio button nor a redirect in your code.

Comment: @Reyno the function does not work

Comment: What function does not work and what is not working exactly? What are you expecting to happen from the current code? We can't magically guess what you are trying to do. Especially if you don't provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in there. I have 3 radio buttons and I would like when users to choose each radio button then redirect to the lightbox page but this part it does not work:`
function event(){
let User1 = $w('#accountAssign').value; // "new value"
if (User1==="Tutor"){
wixWindow.openLightbox("tutorbox")
.then( (data) => {
let receivedData = data;
})}}`

Comment: Please. Help us help you. You said "It does not work". We asked you to define what exactly does not work, you said "it does not work". We asked you again, with more precise questions, like, what is the current behaviour, what is the expected behaviour, what do you mean by "redirect a radio button", try to create a minimal reproductible example, etc. but you just repeated your original question and said "it does not work" again. This is going nowhere :/

Comment: @JeremyThille I mentioned that the function does not work, it's related to the Wix platform. I define a radio button when the user clicks on it, open a new light box that fills information. for example, I have a Tutor radio button, when users checked it show the new lightbox.

Comment: OK so you see, that's already a bit clearer. You want to open a lightbox when clicking a radio button. That's not a redirection. But where is the radio button in the code you provided? There's no such thing. Also, what's in the `(event) =>` handler? (It's empty right now). And I'm not sure naming a function "event" is a good idea, it's probably a reserved word in Javascript. Also, why do you define strings like `const email = "$w('emailInput')"`? you're not using them afterwards. Finally your `$w.onReady(` function is missing closing brackets. What is `$w` by the way?

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks for taking the time, I changed my code and completed another section, I edited my question and put it on, Could you please help me?

Comment: But I'm trying to help you. Seeing your updated code : 1. It's still invalid so it must crash (`$w.onReady` isn't closed); 2. There is still no `<input type="radio"/>` anywhere, so I have no idea what's going on. 3. You define constants within brackets without using any (?) 4. There's a `.onChange((event) =>{  })` that's empty, therefore useless. I see you have added a lot of `import import import` but this is not the issue. Please focus on the issue (the input radio thing).

Comment: Are you trying to do `function openLightbox(){ }` and then `.onChange(openLightbox);` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks, `$w` is related to the Wix platform. I found it we couldn't access to HTML code in Wix so I couldn't see the `<input type="radio"/>`. I couldn't understand this part " You define constants within brackets without using any (?)"

Comment: Aaaaah right, that's Wix stuff, you don't have access to everything. I guess `$w` is Wix's jQuery. "You define constants within brackets without using any" --> You have this function `onReady(() =>` which only contains `const email, const password, const firstName` etc. Only `const` and nothing else. You are defining those constants... and that's it, nothing else. You're not using them or anything

Comment: The function you created onChange `$w("#accountAssign").onChange((event) => {});` does not have an effect as it is empty. If you refer to the `function event()` you might consider changing it to `$w("#accountAssign").onChange(event);` or `$w("#accountAssign").onChange(() => {event()});` and continue from there.